# ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded (Private Route, Login, Home)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-router-v4

I am getting the following error when I add PrivateRoute to my program. It works fine without it. I am not able to figure out where the infinite loop is being created.

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

The following is the reactjs code. The workflow of the program is that when the user logs in they are redirected to the home page and when they click on logout, they are redirected back to the login page.

Home

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCurrentProfile();
    console.log(this.props.auth.isAuthenticatedUser);
    // if (!this.props.auth.isAuthenticatedUser) {
    //   this.props.history.push("/");
    // }
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const { profile, loading } = this.props.profile;

    let homeContent;
    if (profile === null || loading) {
      homeContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      if (Object.keys(profile).length > 0) {
        homeContent = <h1>Hi</h1>;
      } else {
        homeContent = (
          <div>
            <p className="lead text-muted">Welcome {user.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <h1 className="display-4">Dashboard</h1>
              {homeContent}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Home.propTypes = {
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  // deleteAccount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  // profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getCurrentProfile }
)(Home);
```

Login

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticatedUser) {
      this.props.history.push("/home");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticatedUser) {
      this.props.history.push("/home");
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="landing">
            <div className="dark-overlay landing-inner text-light">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="form-container">
                      <div className="login">
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-md-12 m-auto">
                            <h2 className="heading text-center">Log In</h2>
                            </p>
                            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                              <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                  type="email"
                                  className={classnames(
                                    "form-control form-control-sm",
                                    {
                                      "is-invalid": errors.email
                                    }
                                  )}
                                  placeholder="Email Address"
                                  name="email"
                                  value={this.state.email}
                                  onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                                {errors.email && (
                                  <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                    {errors.email}
                                  </div>
                                )}
                              </div>
                              <div className="form-group">
                                <input
                                  type="password"
                                  className={classnames(
                                    "form-control form-control-sm",
                                    {
                                      "is-invalid": errors.password
                                    }
                                  )}
                                  placeholder="Password"
                                  name="password"
                                  value={this.state.password}
                                  onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                                {errors.password && (
                                  <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                    {errors.password}
                                  </div>
                                )}
                              </div>
                              <input
                                type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4"
                              />
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loginUser }
)(Login);
```

Private Route

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**Edit:**
Here's my App.js where I set the PrivateRouter for the Home component

```
..
   <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
            </Switch>

..
```

Answer (score 0):

componentWillRecieveProps has been deprecated, so you should probably find a way with a more upgradable future. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

I think what's happening is that `nextProps.errors` is always true and you're indefinitely setting state. You'd be better off starting the value as `undefined` if you want to use your approach

Basically, `{}` is a truthy value and you want to checking that there are errors, not that the errors object is truthy.

Consider this:

```
let obj = {};

if (obj) {
  console.log("hello")
}

let notObj = undefined;
if (notObj) {
  console.log('world')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me why this problem occurs when I set the home route to PrivateRoute.